# Audio Driver Missing

Tags: drivers, bash, sound, kernel, 20.04

I have just installed Kubuntu 20.04 and oddly enough, while using the live usb's os, audio was working. However after installing the os Audio is not working.

**inxi info**

```
inxi -A

Audio:     Device-1: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] Family 17h HD Audio driver: N/A 
           Device-2: NVIDIA TU102 High Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-31-generic
```

- What can i do to get audio working?
- I have read that linux automatically ships with most of the common drivers that it isn't necessary to download and install any drivers. Seeing that this is not the case here, what should i do to install drivers in general and to install audio drivers as well?

Comment: I would install Pulse Audio Volume Control.  Then play something with VLC like an mp3 or a video.  Then look at output devices and see if there is a setting there to fix.  There are annoying things about Kubuntu(I am a K-User for a long time) and HDMI where the audio gets routed to HDMI. Play with PAVU and report back.

Answer (score 0):

I did nothing to solve this.
However, today upon updating my kernel, sound now is working

The output of `inxi -A` is

```
Audio:
  Device-1: AMD Family 17h HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel 
  Device-2: NVIDIA TU102 High Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-37-generic
```